# Routing in ring network topology

Tags: approximation, network-topology

I want to find 2-approximation algorithm for finding path of **m** messages sent from **m** computers to **m** different computers in a ring topology with **n** nodes.
I know about **clockwise embedding**, which takes hyperedges, which are basically the connection requests and makes path from the lowest numbered node to the highest in the clockwise direction.
This algorithm works when we want to pass the message through more than two computers.
So my question is:
Is this a good algorithm for finding a path between **only two** computers in a ring network or is there an easier 2-approximation algorithm for it?
Edit: Note, that I want the number of messages using the most frequently used edge as low as possible.